# Is there a way to invoke the expression in a cell (or the data structure it yields), rather than its value?

Tags: google-sheets

Someone provided me with a complex formula, that I want to understand and improve.

I started by breaking it apart to see what each part of it yielded, and then chaining the parts to rebuild the whole.

This doesn't work though because some of the parts yield complex data structures rather than simple values.

If there is an expression in say cell E6, I need to be able to refer to that and get the whole data structure it yields, or the expression it contains - is there a way to do that?

For example, let's say that cell `E6` contains a formula that returns not just one value, but several values, in a row of cells:

```
3
5
8
13
```

If I then do `ROWS(E6)`, I will get only the particular value as displayed in `E6` - `3`. What I actually want is the whole set of values that the formula returns, so that `ROWS(E6)` will return `4`.

Comment: You'll need to provide an example of what you mean.  Provide some an example of a before formula/data, and an example of the desired result.

Comment: To get the expression (along with the rest of the formula), use `=formulatext(E6)`. To get the formula result, use `=E6`. To get the result of a part of the formula, take that part of the formula and put it in a cell of its own. To learn more, browser the [function list](https://support.google.com/docs/table/25273).

Comment: Also worth adding that many 'complex' formulas may have a single ARRAYFORMULA wrapper on the outside that enables array operations at multiple points within the formula; if you break a particular element out of a formula that uses array operations you will need to rewrap it in ARRAYFORMULA otherwise the result may be misleading.